# App::abort and App::error

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am working on a centralized error handling in laravel.

What my code looks like:

```
// Bad request
App::error(function(FormValidationException $e, $code) {
    App::abort(400, $e->getErrors());
});

// Unauthenticated
App::error(function(UnauthenticatedExcpetion $e, $code) {
    App::abort(401, 'Unauthenticated');
});

// Unauthorized
App::error(function(UnauthorizedExcpetion $e, $code) {
    App::abort(403, 'Unauthorized');
});

// Http
App::error(function(HttpException $e, $code) {
    return Response::json($e->getMessage(), $code);
});
```

The problem is, that the last one does not get executed from the other ones. I have to do it with `Response` because else Angular `$http` fires a success.

How can I get this to work? (I want to keep it dry, so no multiple `Response:json` please).

Answer (score 0):

Are those exceptions in the global namespace or are you sure that you have `use`d them at the top of the file properly?

Also, `Exception` is spelt incorrectly in both your `unauthenticated` and `unauthorised` handlers.

Comment: They get fired, just the last one not. Yes the typo is real :/

Comment: Once the first exception that isn't caught is thrown in a request it will reach it's error handler and the request will end. It won't fall through to other request handlers. You need to make sure that a properly namespaced `HttpException` is being thrown and not caught if you want that handler to be called upon.

Comment: `App::abort` throws an uncaught HttpException.

Comment: It throws `\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException`. Have you tried catching that?

Comment: It is imported with use, it is the correct Exception.